# understanding the cmp command -s option

Tags: command-line

The man page of cmp command says that '-s' option will suppress all the normal output. Can somebody explain what does the word 'normal' mean here? I tried creating an error scenario (by passing name of a non-existing file) with -s, but still no output was produced. Need help on this.

cmp command man page:
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cmp.1.html

My Ubuntu version is 16.04 and cmp version is 3.3

Answer (score 1):

The man page says `-s` is a synonym for `--quiet` or `--silent`. This tells a lot. The normal output is all the output produced **without** any of the mentioned flags.

```
$ cmp badfile badfile1
cmp: badfile: No such file or directory
$ cmp -s badfile badfile1
$
```

Silent version of commands only set the exit code which is usually processed further in scripts. Example:

```
if cmp -s $file1 $file2; then
    echo "The files are identical."
    # do something
else
    echo "The files are different."
    # do something else
fi
```

Comment: can we make any test case in which cmp -s option should display an output. Also i have read that the cmp -l and -s option together are incompatible. Can you tell what is the reason behind such behaviour ?

Comment: @ashish8496 I don’t think so but you can examine the source code to discover if there is _any_ output _ever_ produced using the _silent_ option. And you don’t get the contradiction of being _silent_ (`-s`) and _verbose_ (`-l`) same time?

Comment: yes, when i run the command using both the options i.e -s and -l, then it gives an error of incompatibility.    For example: if i run the following command, then it will give an error : cmp - l  -s file1.txt  file2.txt..........then it gives an error that options -s and -l are incompatible.